# Increment row index in loop until all rows in a dataframe is processed - python

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, row, increment

I'm reading few rows at a time from a dataframe to process about 1.3M rows for text classification. I'm manually updating the number of rows that should be read and processed using **df.iloc[from_row:to_row]**

I use Colab for the current activity. I have separate blocks of codes that I use as a flow to finally download the classified dataframe of the sliced rows.

Would like to automatically increment the **from_row:to_row** numbers by 100 or 500 or 1000 after the download of the processed dataframe after each increment until the last row is processed

```
temp = temp.iloc[100:201] ##Manually updating this part and running rest of the code

test=[]

**# classifiying sentences in text column**
for row in tqdm(temp['comments'].values):
  res = label_classify(row)
  test.append(res)
temp['test'] = test

**# mapping right labels to appropriate rows**
list_of_rows = temp.test.to_list()
th = 0.4    #whatever threshold value you want
result = list(map(lambda x: get_label_score_dict(x, th), list_of_rows))
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result)

**## concatenating labeled df to original df and downloading (to avoid losing processed data incase Colab reconnects or I lose the session)**
*# Merging dfs*
temp.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
concatenated_df_new = pd.concat( [temp, result_df], axis=1)
merge_df = pd.DataFrame()
merge_df = pd.concat([merge_df,concatenated_df_new], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

**# downloading final dataframe**

from google.colab import files
merge_df.to_csv('merge_nps.csv') 
files.download('merge_nps.csv')
```

There could be an entirely different way to do it. I've been coding in python only for a shorter time now.

any help or ideas of how I can write this as a function or how to increase the counter (df.iloc[**from_row:to_row**]) would be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand why You can't put `df.iloc[:]`...?

Comment: @N.JonasFigge can you please elaborate. didn't understand your suggestion

Comment: Usually, You can use `:` to get all elements - I don't understand why You have to do it successively...

Comment: @N.JonasFigge I'd have to process 1.3M rows and the estimated time to process all rows in Colab is about 17 hours using .apply(lambda row: label_classify(row)) method. So  I'm trying to download my processed output for every iteration to avoid losing processed data incase my session closes out.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to do some kind of batching, you could go with this:

```
import numpy as np

batch_size = 1024   # or whatever you want the batch size to be
num_samples = 1.3e6 # or whatever the exact value is

num_batches = int(np.ceil(num_samples / batch_size))
for i in range(num_batches):
    temp = temp.iloc[i*batch_size : (i+1)*batch_size]

    #... rest of the code
```

Untested, but You get the idea.